# Why stringer can't find the package?

Tags: go

Any idea how can I fix the error below? I have a go generator (stringer) which I try to run but it keeps reporting that it can't find a package import although the package is definitely imported.

```
stringer: checking package: main.go:13:3: could not import example.io/api/util (can't find import: example.io/api/util)
main.go:33: running "stringer": exit status 1
```

Answer (score 8):

From [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/4pgvzvy7O20/discussion):

> Seems to be a silly thing: 4 part import are usually subpackages and these must be "**installed**" before you can use them. I ran the following on the command line to resolve my problem:

So try first:

```
go install <yourpackage>
```

Ad see if go generate works after that.

Make sure to use the latest go 1.4.2 and to update your stringer as well:

```
go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer
```